# PHP Session being reused on another computer

Tags: php, session

Since last week, we are receiving complains from customer that they are receiving emails for orders that they have not placed but are of other users.

My debug says, two customers at two different locations at different times had the same session id and PHP auto logged in the last customer by the previous customer and placed the order.

For example: 
Customer 1: logged in at 9 AM, placed an order (worked well)
Customer 2: logged in at 4 PM, placed an order - but can't find the order confirmation online and in email.

Customer 1 calls customer service that they received confirmation of an order on the name of Customer 2 which they have not placed.

I checked both orders in the database, and they both had same session ID logged against them. Which i found very surprising, i wouldn't expect customer 1 to be online all day.

Obviously its a huge privacy issue.

Can some help me in terms of how can I debug or find the problem or solve it??

I am using $_SESSION to manage login.

The code is being maintained since 5 years. The site has good enough traffic and the code has been working well since then. The issue has suddenly popped up two weeks back and has been happening often with different customers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where your session_ids derived from?  You use `session_id()` for the session id stored in the database?  Are you using the default mechanism for generating session ids? or is the function `session_id(...)` called anywhere in your code?

Comment: i use session_id() to log session id. I am not using any self generated ids or not storing any cookies via code.